# The constructor Intent is undefined

Tags: java, android

I have the content module loaded, the specific error I'm getting is: `The constructor Intent(new View.OnClickListener(){}, Class<ContactWidget>) is undefined`

Any ideas on this?  I got this from the tutorial here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html

```
package com.example.contactwidget;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class ContactWidget extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Button calc1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.calc_button_1);
        calc1.setOnClickListener(buttonListener);

        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }

    private static final int HELLO_ID = 1;

    private OnClickListener buttonListener = new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick (View v) {
            String ns = Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE;
            NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(ns);

            int icon = R.drawable.icon;
            CharSequence ticketBrief = "Button Pressed Brief";
            CharSequence ticketTitle = "Button pressed";
            CharSequence ticketText = "You pressed button 1";
            long when = System.currentTimeMillis();

            Notification notification = new Notification(icon, ticketBrief, when);

            Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, ContactWidget.class);
            PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);

            notification.setLatestEventInfo(getApplicationContext(), ticketTitle, ticketText, contentIntent);

            mNotificationManager.notify(HELLO_ID, notification);
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Change this:

```
new Intent(this, ContactWidget.class);
```

to

```
new Intent(ContactWidget.this, ContactWidget.class);
```

The error happens because, in that case, `this` is referencing the instance of `OnClickListener`, but the `Intent's` constructor expects a `Context`. The context you have to pass is the reference to the activity itself, thus you have to access it explicitly using `ContactWidget.this`.

Comment: Yep, that's it... what's the difference in `ContactWidget.class` and `ContactWidget.this` ?

Comment: `ContactWidget.this` is a reference to an instance of the `ContactWidget class`. ContactWidget.class is a reference to the class itself. The intent need: a context, and a class. In those cases that's the easier thing you can do (send a reference of the class as context), but you can also send another context like the one returned by `getApplicationContext()` method.

Comment: if anyone is using fragments you can use this code 
new Intent(getActivity(), ContactWidget.class);

Comment: Now it is throwing error "No enclosing instance of type Contact Widget is accessible in scope."

Answer (score 2):

The context passed in could be from a remote application host... apparently you need the app context from your app, the one with your class (your broadcast reciever for instance).
Intent intent = new Intent(context.getApplicationContext(), WidgetryBroadcastReceiver.class);
instead of 
Intent intent = new Intent(context, WidgetryBroadcastReceiver.class);
go figure.

Answer (score 0):

yeah that workerd for me aswell for the error in

```
Geocoder gc = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
```