# Intent can't switch between activities-Android 4.0

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-4.2-jelly-bean

This is a weird problem, My intent can't switch between activities in case of Android 4.0+ devices, However, on devices with android 2.2/2.3 it works fine.

This is how I define the intent for my class PhotoActivity.

```
public static final void startActivityForResult(Activity parent, int requestCode, String userName, String photoUrl, Bitmap preview, boolean isMugshot) {
    System.out.println("photoactivity started" +requestCode+"second"+parent);
    Intent intent = new Intent(parent, PhotoActivity.class)
    .putExtra(USERNAME, userName)
    .putExtra(PHOTOURL, photoUrl)
    .putExtra(PREVIEW, preview)
    .putExtra(IS_MUGSHOT, isMugshot);
    parent.startActivityForResult(intent, requestCode);
}
```

I want to switch to this activity class as above from another class upon a particular user touch response. I define this as follows

```
case R.id.ImgAvatar:
        PhotoActivity.startActivityForResult(this, REQUEST_SHOW_AVATOR, mUserName, avatarUrl, mAvatar, true);
        break;
```

My code is fine since in case of android 2.3/2.2 , I can switch in between the actvities. However, while using devices with android 4.0+, Rather than switching between activities upon touch response, I am reverted back to my main activity(clueless why).

I also noticed the console output was different in both 2.2 and 4.0 version. I am still not able to guess why android 4.0 is causing trouble.

This is the log when the activity starts correctly (android 2.2/2.3),

```
  04-11 10:29:21.665: I/System.out(924): photoactivity started userdhttp://www.l-somewhere.com/media/Users/a6cb0167255045a9a2a16bb3411bc2/Mugshot/324c3a02b252428b8676e42671e392c2.jpg
04-11 10:29:21.675: I/System.out(924): photoactivity started4096secondcom.lsomewhere.android.UserDataActivity@44ae2b80
04-11 10:29:21.845: D/dalvikvm(924): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 1481 objects / 289856 bytes in 84ms
04-11 10:29:21.855: I/PhotoActivity(924): onCreate// **rightly called** ,switch of activity
04-11 10:29:21.855: I/pthread(924): ## thread 924 is creating thread @dalvik/vm/Thread.c:1443
04-11 10:29:21.855: I/pthread(924): ## thread 1008 is created success
04-11 10:29:25.325: D/dalvikvm(938): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 1339 objects / 483712 bytes in 69ms
```

This is the log in case of android 4.0+

```
04-11 10:34:47.415: I/System.out(22717): photoactivity started userdhttp://www.l-somewhere.com/media/Users/a6cb0167255045a9a2a16bb3411bc2/Mugshot/324c3a02b252428b8676e42671e392c2.jpg
04-11 10:34:47.420: I/System.out(22717): photoactivity started4096secondcom.lsomewhere.android.UserDataActivity@424d6db0
04-11 10:34:47.520: D/SensorManager(22717): unregisterListener::  Listener= android.view.OrientationEventListener$SensorEventListenerImpl@4201ce20
04-11 10:34:47.525: D/Sensors(22717): Remain listener = Sending .. normal delay 200ms
04-11 10:34:47.525: I/Sensors(22717): sendDelay --- 200000000
04-11 10:34:47.525: D/SensorManager(22717): JNI - sendDelay
04-11 10:34:47.525: I/SensorManager(22717): Set normal delay = true
04-11 10:34:47.745: D/dalvikvm(24379): GC_CONCURRENT freed 184K, 10% free 12467K/13703K, paused 3ms+12ms, total 29ms
04-11 10:34:47.750: W/CursorWrapperInner(24379): Cursor finalized without prior close()
04-11 10:34:47.775: I/MainActivity(24379): RegistrationId, DeviceTocken: //**I don't know why rather than starting the photo activity, the main activity is called,**
```

Clearly, in case of android 4.0+ , my second activity is not called and i am reverted back to main activity. Another interesting observation is that the intent is actually called, i.e. I reach the function where I define the intent, but It seems like intent cannot start the activity, so the intent does run but It can't start the new activity. I am clueless since my code is not giving any run/compile time errors making it difficult to find out the problem. Appreciate the help.

Here is my Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.lsomewhere.android"
android:versionCode="37"
android:versionName="1.0.37" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="16" />

<permission 
    android:name="com.lsomewhere.android.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="com.lsomewhere.android.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>


<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher_72x72"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <uses-library
        android:name="com.google.android.maps"
        android:required="true" />

    <service
        android:name=".LsCommService"
        android:process=":apisrv" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.lsomewhere.android.LSAPISERVICE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <service android:name=".GCMIntentService" />

    <receiver
        android:name="com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

            <category android:name="com.lsomewhere.android" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <activity
        android:name=".SplashActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".LoginActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
        android:label="@string/login"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateUnspecified|adjustPan" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".ProfileActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
        android:label="@string/login"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".AvatarActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
        android:label="@string/upload_your_photo"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".UserDataActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
        android:label="@string/user_data"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".GalleryActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar" 
        >

    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".PhotoActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar"
         >

    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".PasswordActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".AboutActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"

        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".AdvrDataActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar" >
    </activity>
     <activity
        android:name=".PageBase"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar" >
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.lsomewhere.android.TutorialActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"></activity>
    <activity android:name="com.kuad.ADDisplay"/>
</application>
```

Comment: Can you provide AndroidManifest.xml entries for the Activites that you are having problems with.

Comment: you can see that now Morris

Comment: See this link:[link][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4527698/the-constructor-intent-is-undefined

May this will help you..

Comment: nope that doesn't work, the problem is something else since in case of android 2.2 it works perfectly, However for version 4.0+ , it doesn't