# Which is the best method for Activity Change For Android Application

Tags: android

I have two activity. I want to go from A to B with fixed time. After going to B i want to come back to A with fixed time. i have searched for it but could not understand where to start. Should i use `thread` or `timer` or `handler`.

I am trying to understand the below codes:

```
Handler activityChanger = new Handler();  
activityChanger.postDelayed(new Runnable(){
   startActivity(new Intent(this,about.class));
}, 10000);
```

It would be a great help if anyone can give me an example. 
I have added below code.

```
 Thread switchToActivityB = new Thread(new Runnable() {              
 @Override 
          public void run() {
            try {
              Thread.sleep(3000);
              Intent intent = new Intent(this, About.class);
              startActivity(intent);
              finish();
            } catch (Exception e) {

            }
          }
        });
        switchToActivityB.start();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Thread switchToActivityB = new Thread(new Runnable() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
    try {
      Thread.sleep(3000); // The fixed time in milli seconds
      Intent intent = new Intent(activityA.this, activityB.class);
      startActivity(intent);
      finish();
    } catch (Exception e) {
      // Catch Exception
    }
  }
});
switchToActivityB.start();
```

Add this code to Activity A, in onCreate() method

Do the same in Activity B, in onCreate() method

```
Thread switchToActivityA = new Thread(new Runnable() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
    try {
      Thread.sleep(3000); // The fixed time in milli seconds
      Intent intent = new Intent(activityB.this, activityA.class);
      startActivity(intent);
      finish();
    } catch (Exception e) {
      // Catch Exception
    }
  }
});
switchToActivityA.start();
```

Comment: The Constructor Intent (new Runnable(){}, Class<about> in unidentified)

Comment: when i Intent intent = new Intent(this, activityA.class); add this it shows me the upon error. what i should do?

Comment: Donkey bro i need some reply from you.

Comment: Try specifying activityA.this and activityB.this
this was referring to the Thread instead of your activity. So making this change should work. I've also edited in my answer above. Hope this helps [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4527698/the-constructor-intent-is-undefined)

Answer (score 1):

The place to put the code depends of how you want to do. For example, if you want to do this everytime you are in Activity A (that means that when you go to B and then press go back, after a fixed time it will go back to the activity B again), you should put the code in `onResume()` method.

If you just want to do this once, just put it in `onCreate()` method

Answer (score 0):

You can put the above code in onResume() of 1st activity. Similarly, put the same code with little modification of activity name in "about.java" onResume()..

Comment: what is life modification?

Comment: Sorry it was typo error. I mean LITTLE modification of activity name.. I have edited it :)

Answer (score 0):

For what you described you should use that either on `onStart` or `onResume` methods. If you place it on `onCreate` it will run just once, as your activities don't get destroyed.

You can use any of the options you described. `StartActivity` [Is a safe method, so you can call it from outside your UI Thread.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3295847/is-it-safe-to-launch-and-activity-from-a-non-ui-thread)